# How can I detect the CEFR level of an English resource?

Tags: teaching

Suppose, I have an English text (poem book, storybook, novel, article, etc.) or an audio or a video in my hand. I want to use it in my lesson plan.

How can I detect the CEFR level of this English resource which I am planning to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One uses the CEFR descriptors and judgement.

(The older [2001 version descriptors are simpler to use](https://rm.coe.int/CoERMPublicCommonSearchServices/DisplayDCTMContent?documentId=090000168045b15e))

So you ask yourself is this "a straightforward factual text on subjects related to his/her field and interest" (B1)   or is it a "lengthy, complex text, [...] not relate[d] to his/her own area of speciality" (C1)

Thus, almost by definition, any novel or poem (apart from those written for learners or children) will be at B2+ level.

However, this is not the only way to differentiate.  You can differentiate by *support* (Eg provide the lower level learners with a vocabulary list) or by *outcome* (eg the lower level learners are only expected to achieve partial understanding). Or by *time* (give lower-level learners more time).  You can use the same resource, but shorten it for the lower level learners (just look at one stanza of the poem)